# Is it a good practise to create a seperate java file for each class in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, class, design-patterns, r.java-file

[image: New class in Eclipse]

When I create a new class using the above menu ,a new java file is created for each class and as you can see this leads to a lot of .java files very quickly(Why does ellipse show a .class structure inside a .java file, ) , is this a good design practice considering the fact that sometimes I only want classes to be very small such as

```
class Name
{
String firstName;
String lastName;
}
```

I'm new to Eclipse and Java IDE's , can you also tell me a shortcut to create a new class .

Comment: to create a new class in the same file you can use the buttons c l a s s ;-)

Comment: Sorry ,can you be more clear?

Comment: I've tried to maintain java programs where people have tried to stuff as many classes into a single file as possible,  they're much harder to read. You're on the right track with one file per class (and the occasional inner class where it makes sense)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not only good practice, it is the way Java was intended to be written.

[Why is each public class in a separate file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318712/why-is-each-public-class-in-a-separate-file)

Multiple classes in the same file is possible, with [nested classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) and [anonymous classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) and so on, but you should really have a good reason to do such a thing. There is nothing wrong with a small class, and it greatly improves readability when you are not searching through large files looking for internal classes.