# How could I fix my code?

Tags: java

I am using netbeans and keep getting the following errors:

> class interface or enum expected java

class `RainFall` is public, should be declared in a file named `RainFall.java`

This is the code:

```
package rainfalldemo;

/**
 *
 * @author 
 */

    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.text.DecimalFormat;

    public class RainFallDemo {

    /**
     * begin main method
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // declare variables
        final int MAX_MONTHS = 12;
        double totalRainfall;
        double averageRainfall;
        int monthOfMostRain;
        int monthOfLeastRain;

        //create an array of rainfall
        double[] rainfallInYear = new double[MAX_MONTHS];

        //create array of months in a yeat
        String months[] = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May",   
       "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", 
       "December"};

        //call getRainfallValues method
        getRainfallValues(rainfallInYear, months);

        // creaet rainfall class object
        RainFall rainInYear = new RainFall(rainfallInYear);

        // create an object for DecimalFormat class
        DecimalFormat decimals = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

        //display total rainfall in the year
        totalRainfall = rainInYear.getTotalRainfall();
        System.out.println("The total rainfall in the year is: " + 
        totalRainfall);

        //display average monthly rainfall
        averageRainfall = rainInYear.getAverageRainfall();
        System.out.println("The average monthly rainfall is: " + 
        decimals.format(averageRainfall));

        //display the month with most rain
        monthOfMostRain = rainInYear.getMonthOfMostRainfall();
        System.out.println("The month with the most rain: " + 
        rainfallInYear[monthOfMostRain] + " in " + months[monthOfMostRain]);

        //display month with least rain
        monthOfLeastRain = rainInYear.getMonthOfLeastRainfall();
        System.out.println("The month with the least rain: " + 
        rainfallInYear[monthOfLeastRain] + " in " + months[monthOfLeastRain]);

        }//end of main method

        //getRainfallValues method implementation
        public static void getRainfallValues(double[]rainfallInEachMonth, 
        String[]    monthNames)
        {
        //create an object for Scanner class
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        // get rain for every month
        for(int i = 0; i < rainfallInEachMonth.length; i++)
        {
            //prompt user for rainfall in a month
            System.out.print("enter the total rainfall for the month " + 
            monthNames[i] + ": ");
            rainfallInEachMonth[i] = input.nextDouble();
            /* verify whether the rain in the month is negative */
                    while(rainfallInEachMonth[i] < 0)
                    {
                        System.out.print("Enter positive value for rainfall: ");
                        rainfallInEachMonth[i] = input.nextDouble();
                    } //end while
        } //end for
        System.out.println();
    } //end of getRainfallValues method

    }//end of RainfallDemo class
```

RainFall.java

```
    //RainFall class

    public class RainFall
    {
    // variable declaration
    private double[] rainInYear;

    public RainFall(double[] rainfallInEachMonth)
    {
        rainInYear = new double[rainfallInEachMonth.length];

        //store rainfall
        for(int  i = 0; i < rainfallInEachMonth.length; i++)
            rainInYear[i] = rainfallInEachMonth[i];
    } // end of parameterized constructor

      //get TotalRainfall method implementation
    public double getTotalRainfall()
    {
        //local variable 
        double totalRainfall = 0.0;
        //calculate the total rainfall in the year
        for(int i= 0; i < rainInYear.length; i++)
            totalRainfall += rainInYear[i];
        return totalRainfall;
    } // end getTotalRainfall method

    //getAverageRainFall method implementation
    public double getAverageRainfall()
    {
        //local variable
        double averageRainfall = 0.0;

        //calculate the average rainfall in a year
        averageRainfall = getTotalRainfall() / rainInYear.length;
        //return averageRainfall
        return averageRainfall;
    } // end of getTotalRainfall method

    //getMonthOfMostRainfall method implementation
    public int getMonthOfMostRainfall()
    {
        // local variable
        double most;
        int monthNumber;
        //initialize variables

        most = rainInYear[0];
        monthNumber = 0;
        //loop repeats to find the month of most rainfall
        for(int i = 1; i < rainInYear.length; i++)
        {
            // find the most rainfall
            if(rainInYear[i] > most)
            {
                most = rainInYear[i];
                monthNumber = i;
            }//end if 
        }  //end for loop
     //return month of most rainfall
        return monthNumber;
    } //end of getMonthOfMostRainfall method

    //getMonthOfLeastRainfall method implementation
    public int getMonthOfLeastRainfall()
    {
        //local variable
        double least;
        int monthNumber;
        //initialize the variables

        least = rainInYear[0];
        monthNumber = 0;
        //loop repeats to find the month of least rainfall
        for(int i = 1; i < rainInYear.length; i++)
        {
            //find least rainfall month
            if(rainInYear[i] < least)
            {
                least = rainInYear[i];
                monthNumber = i;
            }// end if
        } // end for loop
        // return the month of least rainfall
        return monthNumber;
    }// end of getMonthOfLeastRainfall method

} // end of RainFall class
```

Comment: Remove the `public` Access modifier with `class RainFall`

Comment: It's unclear whether this code sample is all contained in one file...  The OP has `RainFall.java` in the middle, which implies he's quoting from a separate file.  The OP also has a bizarre casing issue (`RainFAll is public`...) in his quoted error message, but that may be due to user-error when quoting into his post.

Comment: Now it appears that `RainFall` is in its own file. But that makes the error message nonsensical. @Wil, would you please clarify? Is `RainFall` in its own file, RainFall.java? Or in the same file as `RainFallDemo`?

Comment: It should all be in the same file.

Comment: Madushan, you're a genius. thank you very much. And thanks to everyone for your help I greatly appreciate your responses. I look forward to helping others in the future just as you have helped me. Removing the public modifier with class RainFall worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can not have more than one public class in a single file.Take it out and put it in a file as suggested to you in error and you will be good.

From [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/#26783)

> This restriction implies that there must be at most one such type per
>   compilation unit. This restriction makes it easy for a Java compiler
>   to find a named class within a package. In practice, many programmers
>   choose to put each class or interface type in its own compilation
>   unit, whether or not it is public or is referred to by code in other
>   compilation units.

### See Also

- [Why is each public class in a separate file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318712/why-is-each-public-class-in-a-separate-file)
- [Java: Multiple class declarations in one file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336692/java-multiple-class-declarations-in-one-file)