# Can only make one extended class in java, the other ones have to be in own file apparently

Tags: java, extends, superclass

I have been trying to make three different extended classes from a superclass. The problem is that only the first extended class works fine while the other two gets an error when I name them, and its says they should be in their own file. I have looked around to see if someone had a similar problem, but nothing exactly like this. The extended class that is working is the first one called "Smycken".

here is the code:

```
abstract public class Vardesaker 
{
private String name;
double value;

public Vardesaker(String name, double value)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.value = value;
}

public String getName()
{
    return name;
}

 abstract public double getValue();
}

class Smycken extends Vardesaker
{
    private int adelstenar;
    private String material;
    public Smycken(String name, double value, int adelstenar, String material)
{
    super(name, 0);
    this.adelstenar = adelstenar;
    this.material = material;
}

public int getadelstenar()
{
    return adelstenar;
}

public String getMaterial()
{
    return material;
}

public double getValue()
{
    if(material.equalsIgnoreCase("guld"))
    {
        double sum = 2000 + (500*adelstenar);
        value = sum*1.25;
    }
    else
    {
        double sum = 700 + (500*adelstenar);
        value = sum*1.25;
    }
    return value;


    }
}


public class Aktier extends Vardesaker
{
    private double kurs;
    private int amount;

    public Aktier (String name, double value, int amount, double kurs)
    {
        super(name, 0);
        this.kurs = kurs;
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public double getKurs()
    {
        return kurs;
    }

    public int getAmount()
    {
        return amount;
    }

    public double getValue()
    {
        double sum = (int) (amount*kurs);
        value = sum*1.25;

        return value;
    }


}

public class Apparater extends Vardesaker
{
    private double price;
    private int slitage;

    public Apparater(String name, double value, double price, int slitage)
    {
        super(name, 0);
        this.price = price;
        this.slitage = slitage;
    }

    public double getPrice()
    {
        return price;
    }

    public int getSlitage()
    {
        return slitage;
    }

    public double getValue()
    {
        double sum = price*(slitage/10);
        value = sum*1.25;

        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: What part of the error don't you understand?

Comment: I don't understand why the extended class called smycken works, but not the other extended classes called aktier and apparater?

Answer (score 3):

It is not because of extends, it is because of `public` keyword for the other classes. If you create multiple class with `public` keyword then they should be in their own *compilation unit*.

Check [this answer for why each public class should have separate file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318712/why-is-each-public-class-in-a-separate-file).

Answer (score 3):

There is a simple rule - 1 public type (class,interface,enum) = 1 java file