# (in Android) Do Activity classes need to be in a separate .java file?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, tabs

I am  new to android development and am currently working my way through the "Hello..." Tutorials on the [developer website](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/index.html).

I got stuck on the Tab Layout walkthrough and the only way I could resolve it was to put each Activity Class in a separate .java file.

I was wondering if all Activities need to be in separate .java files, or am I missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/968347/can-a-java-file-have-more-than-one-class). The answer is no, because Java does not allow it (with the exceptions discussed in the responses to my link).

Comment: Cheers, I think I understand, should I be able to get it to work if I nest public Activity classes in the top level public class?

Comment: Activity classes are public, so the answer is no again. There can only be one public class in a Java file and it must have the same name as the file.

Comment: Why are you trying to get them into one file to begin with?

Comment: Right, I am with you now. I just wanted one file which would have all the classes in it, I didn't realise that Activity Classes have to be public. Thanks.