# Java Extending class containing main method

Tags: java

I have the following code as part of an assignment

```
class Base {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("Hello World");
  }
}

public class Factorial extends Base{


}
```

My task is run the code and then explain the output.The name of the file is ***Factorial.java***. The code runs without problem and Hello World is printed which to me is surprising. Before typing the code, I was thinking that it wont compile because the parent class, which is being extended should be in another file but now I am not so sure. Would appreciate soome clarification.

Comment: Homework? Anyway, nothing strange here. Why are you confused?

Comment: I don't get it, do you mean `Factorial` is in the same file as `Base`? How do you "run the code"?

Comment: So the command you use to run it is "java Factorial"?

Comment: You can have more than one java class in a java file. Here is an explanation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/968347/can-a-java-file-have-more-than-one-class

Comment: @digitaljoel Are you sure? I havent run it, but it looks fine to me - one pair enclosing Base, one pair enclosing main, and one pair enclosing Factorial.

Comment: You can have more than one class in a file but only one public class. [**More info**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/968347/can-a-java-file-have-more-than-one-class)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Java allows you to define multiple classes within a single `.java` file with the condition that you can have ***at most*** one `public` class and **if** you do then the name of that public class must match the name of the `.java` file. In your case, the class declared `public` is `Factorial` and hence your file name has to be `Factorial.java`.

The **inheritance** is working as usual here and the `public static void main()` is inherited by `Factorial` which is why you see your output on executing `java Factorial`.

Answer (score 1):

You can have more than one class in the same file, but only one public , as `Base` isn't a public class, but it's not a recommended practice.

Comment: And am I right in assuming that since the extending class inherits the main function from the parent class, it is executed as soon as the program runs?

Comment: @user1107888 yes, as `Factorial` extends `Base` it also inherits the main method.

Comment: @user1107888 the `main` method is static; it is associated with the class itself. Since `Factorial` extends `Base` and `Factorial` does not define `main`, the `main` "seen" by `Factorial` is the one from `base`.