# How to compile several classes in one ,java file

Tags: java, java-console

I would like to compile in a java source file with two classes. How can I do that? I compile my code with:

```
javac -classpath Class_ex_1.java
```

```
public class Class_ex_1 { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        int del = 7;
        int del_1 = 2;
        int rem = del % del_1;
        System.out.println("First value :" + del + "\n");
        System.out.println("Second value :" + del_1 + "\n"); // 
        System.out.println("Display meaning a % b :" + rem + "\n"); //              
            
        Hello_test n1 = new Hello_test();
        System.out.println("Display parameter from class:" + n1.getColor + "\n");
                        
    }
}
    
public class Hello_test {
    String color = "Red";       
    public String getColor(){
        return color;
    }           
}
```

Comment: The JLS allows only a single public class per file, and the class must have the same name as the file (`FileName.java` -> `public Class FileName { ... }`). Thus, the code presented is not valid java code and can therefore not be compiled.

Comment: Step 1: Remove `public` from classes that are not named the same as the file. --- Step 2: Remove `-classpath` from the command.

Comment: I did that, I got error :
javac Class_ex_1.java
Class_ex_1.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
System.out.println("Display parameter from class:" + n1.getColor + "\n");
^
symbol: variable getColor
location: variable n1 of type Hello_test
1 error

Comment: You're invoking the method incorrectly.  Change `n1.getColor`   to `n1.getColor()`

Comment: Your Question seems to be mutating in the comment thread. The fact that you get a new error when you fix the original one is irrelevant to this Question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can a java file have more than one class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/968347/can-a-java-file-have-more-than-one-class)

Comment: @Scratte You are right. The Question is mutated, but i thought it somehow relates to javac,But it turned out to be just wrong code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Hello_test{}
```

Simply remove public from the second class. Also make sure the other class is inside of the Class_ex_1

Comment: I did that, I got error :
javac Class_ex_1.java
Class_ex_1.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
System.out.println("Display parameter from class:" + n1.getColor + "\n");
^
symbol: variable getColor
location: variable n1 of type Hello_test
1 error

Answer (score 1):

The following code doesn't compile because it cannot find `getColor`

```
public class Class_ex_1 { 

   public static void main(String[] args) {        
      int del = 7;
      int del_1 = 2;
      int rem = del % del_1;
      System.out.println("First value :" + del + "\n");
      System.out.println("Second value :" + del_1 + "\n"); // 
      System.out.println("Display meaning a % b :" + rem + "\n"); //              
          
      Hello_test n1 = new Hello_test();
      System.out.println("Display parameter from class:" + n1.getColor + "\n");
                      
   }
}
    
class Hello_test {
   String color = "Red";       
   public String getColor(){
      return color;
   }           
}
```

So it should instead, look like the following:

```
class Class_ex_1 { 

 


   public static void main(String[] args) {        
      int del = 7;
      int del_1 = 2;
      int rem = del % del_1;
      System.out.println("First value :" + del + "\n");
      System.out.println("Second value :" + del_1 + "\n"); // 
      System.out.println("Display meaning a % b :" + rem + "\n"); //              
          
      Hello_test n1 = new Hello_test();
      System.out.println("Display parameter from class:" + n1.getColor() + "\n");
                      
   }
}
    
class Hello_test {
   String color = "Red";   
       
   public String getColor(){
      return color;
   }          
       

}
```

Remember that when we call a method, we need to have a set of parenthesis at the end.

Comment: You've answered a different question to the one asked in the Question.

Comment: @Scratte It was just more verbose answer, although slightly mutated.

Comment: @TheCreatingCoder Thank you very much, for comprehensive reply!!

Comment: @BilowYuriy No, it does not. It answers your other question, but doesn't at all address "How to compile several classes in one ,java file".

Comment: @Scratte Ok, you are right! I set right mark to other question